# How to cut of designs from SVG in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have artboards that has some part of designs out of it, when I export my artboard as SVG and also click `Use Artboards`

[image: one]

yet those extra parts will be included exported file.

[image: two]

Any suggestion how to cut of those extra parts so they not be included exported file?

Comment: Couldn't you maybe select the overlapping objects and delete them?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to resolve this by making a rectangle the same size as your artboard, selecting all of your artwork, and then going (Object > Clipping Mask > Make) to make a clipping mask. This will crop everything that falls outside of the rectangle, and should make the SVG export's final result display as intended. From what I understand, "Use Artboards" on export doesn't work with SVGs the way you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the ideal solution but it will get the job done:

- Draw a rectangle the size of the artboard. The colors don't matter.
- Select everything (with ctr+a or just drag selecting; make sure all layers are unlocked).
- Use the Shape Builder Tool (shift+m) and alt-click and drag on all the items outside of the box. Alternatively, you can turn on the pathfinder window and use the available options there, but this will chop up your design.
- Delete your rectangle and export.